# Can beef bourguignon be halal?

Tags: beef, alcohol, bacon, halal

I'm preparing for the next master chef and want to show off. But I only eat halal. Can it be prepared without alcohol, bacon and cream?

Comment: Being that combative when you don't even know us does not promote your cause. Thank you for pointing out the issue, it is an easily fixed oversight.

Comment: Yes, the fact that you are the first to ask a question that requires a tag does not say anything about the community. Your rush to judgment says more about you.

Comment: Isn't cream considered halal? http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18477/are-there-any-special-rules-about-dairy-foods

Comment: Questions about religious restrictions cannot be answered here, it is up to a religious authority to define what is halal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, Boeuf Bourguignon contains wine. However, non-alcoholic wine can work just fine. Bacon and cream are optional. You can tweak the recipes to make the final product exceptional.

Comment: Doesn't most "non-alcoholic" wine contain some alcohol, making it haram?

Comment: Some non-alcoholic wine does contain trace alcohol, I know that some "wine" is considered halal.

Comment: FWIW, the resulting dish is allowed for consumption when the alcoholic content is not sufficient to intoxicate a person. That may well be the case for this dish.